# Flutter Forms: Is there a way to change the color of the input text based on some condition?

Tags: flutter, flutter-form-builder

Is there a way to change the colour of the input text based on some condition ? The `inputFormatters` only seem to apply to structuring the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the input text color using **TextStyle**

Here is a code sample:

```
TextField(
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
  ...
)
```

You can introduce a condition using a boolean called 'myCondition' and a Ternary Operator in the following way:

```
TextField(
      style: TextStyle(color: myCondition ? Colors.red : Colors.blue),
  ...
    )
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle-class.html